# Can you use the Secure File API if the container doesn't have bash? Like Alpine?

Tags: gitlab, bash, alpine

GitLab offers a [Project-level Secure Files](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secure_files/), the API has you add this to your `.gitlab-ci.yml`,

```yaml
test:
  variables:
    SECURE_FILES_DOWNLOAD_PATH: './where/files/should/go/'
  script:
    - curl --silent "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer" | bash
```

However, I'm using the [Terraform image which is Alpine without bash](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/-/blob/master/Dockerfile) which the [installer script requires](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer).

How can you use Secure File API if your container doesn't have bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the only option when your container doesn't have bash is to add it. With Alpine you can do that with `apk add bash`. You can do that with [`before_script`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script) like this,

```yaml
test:
  variables:
    SECURE_FILES_DOWNLOAD_PATH: './where/files/should/go/'
  before_script:
    - apk add bash
  script:
    - curl --silent "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer" | bash
```